# margin: 0 auto property values listed once vs twice

Tags: css, alignment, margin, center

I'm brushing up on some basic CSS and I stumbled upon a tutorial that said to use:

```css
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
```

as opposed to...

```css
margin: 0 auto;
```

by itself, to center something.

Can someone explain to me if there's any difference between putting 0 auto once, instead of twice? When I code, I don't notice a difference, so my guess is that using 0 auto, once is a short-hand that does the exact same thing.

Comment: ``margin: top right bottom left;`` or you can use ``margin: (top-bottom) (right-left);`` so no diference with your values

Comment: It's shorthand similar to the way that #fff is shorthand for #ffffff. With measurable values, CSS shorthand generally follows a clockwise pattern starting at the top: top, right, bottom, left. A single value supplies all four, two values alternate, and three give distinct values for top and bottom while repeating the second value for left and right.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` is shorthand for `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;`, or `margin: top/bottom left/right`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no diffrence between

```
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
```

and

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

[you can read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

> When one value is specified, it applies the same margin to all four sides.
>
> When two values are specified, the first margin applies to the top and
>   bottom, the second to the left and right.
>
> When three values are specified, the first margin applies to the top,
>   the second to the left and right, the third to the bottom.
>
> When four values are specified, the margins apply to the top, right,
>   bottom, and left in that order (clockwise).